# Google Maps v3 marker over infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, marker

I need to display marker over opened infowindow.
Here is an example of what I'd like to do
[image]

If I understand correctly, the property zindex for marker and infowindow not act for each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the `z-index` property works only along with the same type of objects **(relative z-index)**. Marker z-indexes compared with other Markers, Polygons with other Polygons, and InfoWindows with other InfoWindows. Each of these types have their own layer z-index related to each other that cannot be overridden. [Maps API #InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) and [Maps API #PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions); check z-index description. It's written throughout the API documentation.

I don't remember the exact order of the main layers, but it can be tested easily. For sure though InfoWindows appear above Markers.

Answer (score 0):

:) 1> marker you can use image to set image of default marker google.
2 : InfoWindowOptions  can display HTML inner.