# Marker over Infobubble in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put a google.maps.Marker object over (z-index positioning) an [Infobubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) object

but i am having no success.
Basically what i'm doing is assigning **zIndex: n** to the **markerOptions** object which I pass to the Marker constructor as follow:

```
var markerOptions = {
    position: store.getLocation(),
    title: store.getDetails().title,
    icon: DEFAULT_MARKER,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(20,5),
    zIndex: 2
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
```

I have already read this answer [Google Maps v3 marker over infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819954/google-maps-v3-marker-over-infowindow) but actually it has not got any votes. Can somebody tell me more about?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah this isn't possible I'm pretty sure is the problem.  Google maps has specific layers that are predetermined for where the map itself is drawn, where the text overlays are drawn, where the roads are drawn, where the shapes/polygons are drawn, where the traffic is drawn, where the info windows are drawn, etc.  So basically these are in a set stack and you can't change it, you would have to make custom Overlays and stack them in yourself I think (this might have changed but last I used it you couldn't modify built in Overlay order).

Comment: Thanks for answering shaunhusain. Really nice explanation I really appreciated. It seems the unique way to achieve my desidered result is to inject my markers' layer inside the infobubbles' layer to make z-indexes visible among themselves.. I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as commented by  shaunhusain is the fixed pane where particular elements will be drawn.

It's correct that you need to use a custom overlay, but you must use it to draw the marker, not the infobubble.

The reason: infobubble is an implementation of a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays), it will be drawn inside the `floatPane`. To put the marker on top the infobubble must be drawn into a pane with a zIndex equal or lower than the zIndex of the pane where the marker will be drawn. 
But here comes the problem: all these panes do not receive mouse-events, you wouldn't be able to interact with the infobubble(select tabs, select text, click links, close the infobubble).

Therefore you must use a custom overlay to draw the markers, and you must put these overlays into  the  floatPane(it's the pane with the highest zIndex)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Dr.Molle. Also, thanks for the solution you proposed. I will dive into the issue within few days and I will post other questions I have eventually.